# My downloads keep getting interrupted by network errors

Tags: networking, download, connection

I've been having troubles with downloading certain files for a good while, I think since I got my new computer actually. When it happens, my download randomly suddenly stops (it doesn't even stop after reaching 0 bytes/s, it just happens out of nowhere), sometimes after only a couple seconds, sometimes after a few minutes. On Google Chrome, it immediately shows "Failed - Network Error" , and I have to manually restart the download. This issue seems to happen on a site basis, meaning it never happens on certain sites, and always happen on the other sites.

For Google Chrome, I tried Download managers without success. I also tried to use an add-on that auto-resumes the download, although I have yet to find one that's doing a good job. However, the issue isn't just limited to Google Chrome. It also happens on certain MMORPG patchers, such as FFXIV. I've been able to bypass the issue by connecting to a VPN, although the VPN I got cuts my download speed to like 10%. Also, this problem only affects downloads, I have yet to see it become a problem when playing online games.

So I'd like to get to the core of the problem. Do you have any idea of how I could fix this problem without resorting to add-ons? I am on a Windows 10 Personal Computer, using a wireless connection. The internet itself isn't an issue since it wasn't happening on my old computer, nor is it happening on my phone or on any other computer in my house, so the issue is really something on my computer.

Tell me if there's any other information you need.

Comment: Your first stop should be your ISP Support.

Comment: I would definitely try hard-wiring to your router using an ethernet cable to see if that fixes it.